# Git and bitbucket: How to make a branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am just starting with Git as a heads up:

I have successfully done the basics with a master (clone, make changes, commit changes).

Now I want to do the same operations but with a local development branch to experiment with so I don't mess up the master code that is working.

Do I have to use the web GUI to create a new branch? On my computer, I typed the following:

```
git branch devel
git checkout devel
*modify file a*
git add a
git commit -m "changed a"
git push
```

Now it appears that it has worked! I can switch between devel and master and see the differences are kept. However, nothing is updated on bitbucket, and there is not even a devel branch listed. What am I missing?

Comment: In Git, each repository is its own, fully functional workspace. You branched and committed successfully in your OWN workspace - not the remote one hosted on the internet! You need to PUSH your changes to the remote repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your remote (BitBucket) doesn't know anything about your new branches until you tell it.  You'll have to sync them up the first time by explicitly pushing your new branch:

```
git push <remote> <branch>
git push origin devel
```

After this BitBucket will know about the `devel` branch, and it will show up on fetches, pushes, etc without having to specify it.

[More reading **here**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches).

Comment: Great! It's so simple. But getting to this point took a few hours. Thanks.